# Opencart 3.02 New library class, It does not work

Tags: class, opencart

I have a server in the cloud with the following features:
Centos 7.2
Opencart 3.0.2

I'm creating a new class called Delivery, I invoke one of its functions from / catalog / model / checkout / order / addOrder

I command it to call like this:

```
$ date_delivery = $ this-> customer-> termFinal ($ day, $ month, $period);
```

This new class calculates the delivery time for orders from the day month and the number of delivery days.
I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function 
getCustomerConfiguration () on null in 
/var/www/html/system/library/cart/customer.php:742 Stack trace: # 0 / var 
/ www / html / catalog / model /checkout/order.php(409): Cart \ Customer-> 
termFinal ('16 ',' 10 ',' 2 ') 
# 1 / var / www / html / system / storage / modification / system / engine / loader. php (248): ModelCheckoutOrder-> updateOrderAuth (Array) 
# 2 /var/www/html/system/engine/proxy.php(47): Loader -> {closure} (Array, Array) 
# 3 / var / www / html / catalog / controller / account / order_auth.php (516): Proxy -> __ call ('updateOrderAuth', Array) 
# 4 /var/www/html/system/storage/modification/system/engine/action.php(79 ): ControllerAccountOrderAuth-> update () 
# 5 /var/www/html/catalog/controller/startup/router.php(25): Action-> execute (Object (Registry)) 
# 6 / var / www / html / system /storage/modification/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerStartupRouter-> index () 
# 7 /var/www/html/system/engine/router.php(72): Action-> execute (Object (Registry )) 
# 8 /var/www/html/system/engine/router.php(61): Router-> execute (Object (Action)) 
# 9 / v in /var/www/html/system/library/cart/customer.php on line 742
```

The getCustomerConfiguration () function points to the class: library / cart / cart

This is part of the Delivery class:

```html
namespace Cart;
class Delivery {

 private $ anio;
    private $ holidays;
    private $ holidays Mobile = array ();
    private $ holidays = array ();
    private $ dateDelivery;
    

public function __construct ($ registry) {
   
      $ this-> config = $ registry-> get ('config');
      $ this-> customer = $ registry-> get ('customer');
      $ this-> cart = $ registry-> get ('cart');
      $ this-> session = $ registry-> get ('session');
      $ this-> db = $ registry-> get ('db');
      $ this-> tax = $ registry-> get ('tax');
             
      $ this-> cart-> getCustomerConfiguration (); <=== THIS IS THE FUNCTION
   
      $ anio = date ("Y");
      $ holidays = ($ this-> session-> data ['holidays'])? $ this-> session-> data ['holidays']: 0;

    (! empty ($ anio))? $ this-> anio = (int) ($ anio): null;
    (! empty ($ holidays))? $ this-> holidays = explode (",", $ holidays): null;
    
        if (! empty ($ holidays)) {
        foreach ($ this-> holidays as $ date) {
        $ this-> holidays [] = $ date. "-". $ this-> anio;
        }
         }
               
        // Thursday and Good Friday
      
      $ date = explode ('-', $ this-> jvSanto ($ this-> anio));
      
        $ this-> holidays [] = date ("j-n-Y", mktime (0,0,0, $ date [1], $ date [0] -3, $ date [2]));
        $ this-> holidays [] = date ("j-n-Y", mktime (0,0,0, $ date [1], $ date [0] -2, $ date [2]));
      
        // I add Mobile Holidays
        
        foreach ($ this-> feriadosMoviles as $ fecha) {
        for ($ f = $ this-> anio; $ f <($ this-> anio + 1); $ f ++) {
        
        $ holiday = $ date. "-". $ f;
                $ diaFeriado = $ this-> getDiaSemana ($ holiday);
                // $ dia = $ diaFeriado ['dia'];
                // $ correction = 0;
                
                $ this-> holidays [] = $ this-> getStringDate ($ diaFeriado ['unix']);
            }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already assigned `$ this-> cart`:

```
$ this-> cart = $ registry-> get ('cart');
```